# Classifying text documents with random forests

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, random-forest

I've a set of 4k text documents.
They belong to 10 different classes.
I'm trying to see how random forest method performs classification.
The issue is my feature extraction class extracts 200k features.(A combination of words,bigrams,collocations etc.)
This is highly sparse data and random forest implementation in sklearn does not work with sparse data inputs.

Q. What are my options here? Reduce number of features ? How ?
Q. Is there any implementation of random forest out there which work with sparse array.

My relevant code is as follows:

```
import logging
import numpy as np
from optparse import OptionParser
import sys
from time import time
#import pylab as pl

from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from special_analyzer import *


data_train  =  load_files(RAW_DATA_SRC_TR)
data_test   =  load_files(RAW_DATA_SRC_TS)
# split a training set and a test set
y_train, y_test = data_train.target, data_test.target

vectorizer = CountVectorizer( analyzer=SpecialAnalyzer()) # SpecialAnalyzer is my class extracting features from text
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(data_train.data)



rf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=10,max_features=10)
rf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: I have only used RF in Java, but it seems you need to make a "normed" vector representation of each document. In Java this can be represented first as a SortedMap<String, double> where the string key is the feature, and the double val is the freq of the term in that doc. if you vectorize everything like this then represent each doc as a standard double[] array, the algorithm should do it's thing. In other words is DOC1 looks like a,b and DOC2 looks like a,c, the after norm/vectoization doc 1 should become a=1,b=1,c=0 and DOC2 would be a=1,b=0,c=1.

Comment: From [the doc of version 0.16.1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.fit) it seems that `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.fit` now accept sparse matrix as input: `Parameters: X : array-like or sparse matrix of shape = [n_samples, n_features]`

Answer (score 6):

Several options: take only the most 10000 most popular features by passing `max_features=10000` to `CountVectorizer` and convert the results to a dense numpy array with the to array method:

```
X_train_array = X_train.toarray()
```

Otherwise reduce the dimensionality to 100 or 300 dimensions with:

```
pca = TruncatedSVD(n_components=300)
X_reduced_train = pca.fit_transform(X_train)
```

However in my experience I could never make a RF work better than a well tuned linear model (such as logistic regression with grid searched regularization parameter) on the original sparse data (possibly with TF-IDF normalization).

Comment: s/RandomizedPCA/TruncatedSVD

Comment: by using max_features I can get it going..But I guess I finding the same behaviour that RF don't outperform linear model.

Comment: Which parameters did you found that are the optimum for a well tunned logistic regression @ogrisel?

Comment: Well it depends on the data. There is no universally good value of the hyperparameters otherwise there would be no point in running a grid search to tune them in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Option 1:
"If the number of variables is very large, forests can be run once with all the variables, then run again using only the most important variables from the first run."

from: http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#giniimp

I'm not sure about the random forest in sklearn has a feature importance option.  The random forest in R implements mean decrease in gini impurity as well as mean decrease in accuracy.

Option 2:
Do dimensionality reduction.  Use PCA or another dimension reduction technique to change the dense matrix of N dimensions into a smaller matrix and then use this smaller less sparse matrix for the classification problem

Option 3:
Drop correlated features.  I believe the random forest is supposed to be more robust to correlated features compared to multinomial logistic regression.  That being said... it could be the case that you have a number of correlated features. If you have a lot of pairwise correlated variables, you can drop one of the two variables and you should in theory not lose "predictive power".  In addition to pairwise correlation there is also multiple correlations.  Check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor

Comment: Thanks for a quick response Andrew, do you have any example R code that can help going..I'm mostly familiar with python.

Comment: I added a bit more about correlated variables as well... This can greater reduce the number of variables as well as give you a lot of insight into your inputs.  Let me know if any of this works/helps

Comment: I'll try out your suggestions and post results here. Thanks.

Comment: Re: option 2, feature selection using `LinearSVC(penalty='l1', C=some_value).fit_transform(X)` is another good way to reduce the dimensionality.

Comment: `I'm not sure about the random forest in sklearn has a feature importance option` it does have `feature_importances_` so yes (don't know why `_`, but it's documented so must be public).