# TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0] while using RF classifier?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I am learning about random forests in scikit learn and as an example I would like to use Random forest classifier for text classification, with my own dataset. So first I vectorized the text with tfidf and for classification:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
classifier=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10) 
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)           
prediction = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

When I run the classification I got this:

```
TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.
```

then I used the `.toarray()` for `X_train` and I got the following:

```
TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]
```

From a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689141/classifying-text-documents-with-random-forests) as I understood I need to reduce the dimensionality of the numpy array so I do the same:

```
from sklearn.decomposition.truncated_svd import TruncatedSVD        
pca = TruncatedSVD(n_components=300)                                
X_reduced_train = pca.fit_transform(X_train)               

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier                 
classifier=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)                  
classifier.fit(X_reduced_train, y_train)                            
prediction = classifier.predict(X_testing)
```

Then I got this exception:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py", line 419, in predict
    n_samples = len(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 192, in __len__
    raise TypeError("sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz()"
TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]
```

The I tried the following:

```
prediction = classifier.predict(X_train.getnnz())
```

And got this:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py", line 419, in predict
    n_samples = len(X)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Two questions were raised from this: How can I use Random forests to classify correctly? and what's happening with `X_train`?.

Then I tried the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/path/file.csv',
header=0, sep=',', names=['id', 'text', 'label'])



X = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(df['text'].values)
y = df['label'].values



from sklearn.decomposition.truncated_svd import TruncatedSVD
pca = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2)
X = pca.fit_transform(X)

a_train, a_test, b_train, b_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

classifier=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
classifier.fit(a_train, b_train)
prediction = classifier.predict(a_test)

from sklearn.metrics.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, confusion_matrix, classification_report
print '\nscore:', classifier.score(a_train, b_test)
print '\nprecision:', precision_score(b_test, prediction)
print '\nrecall:', recall_score(b_test, prediction)
print '\n confussion matrix:\n',confusion_matrix(b_test, prediction)
print '\n clasification report:\n', classification_report(b_test, prediction)
```

Comment: added replicable code to my answer

Comment: there is no need to call the vectorizer on the class labels. `X_test_r = tfidf_vect.transform(df['Label'])`. This should just be an array of the labels. You also need to pass the class lables as the second parameter to `train_test_split`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bit unclear if you are passing the same data structure (type and shape) to the `fit` method and `predict` method of the classifier. Random forests will take a long time to run with a large number of features, hence the suggestion to reduce the dimensionality in the post you link to.

You should apply the SVD to both the training and test data so the classifier in trained on the same shaped input as the data you wish to predict for. Check the input to the fit, and the input to the predict method have the same number of features, and are both arrays rather than sparse matrices.

**updated with example:**
**updated to use dataframe**

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_vect= TfidfVectorizer(  use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True, sublinear_tf=False)
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

df= pd.DataFrame({'text':['cat on the','angel eyes has','blue red angel','one two blue','blue whales eat','hot tin roof','angel eyes has','have a cat']\
              ,'class': [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,3]})



X = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(df['text'].values)
y = df['class'].values

from sklearn.decomposition.truncated_svd import TruncatedSVD        
pca = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2)                                
X_reduced_train = pca.fit_transform(X)  

a_train, a_test, b_train, b_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 

classifier=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)                  
classifier.fit(a_train.toarray(), b_train)                            
prediction = classifier.predict(a_test.toarray())
```

Note the SVD happens before the split into training and test sets, so that the array passed to the predictor has the same `n` as the array the `fit` method is called on.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the example I tried to adapt it for my case, still have problems.. maybe I got confused, do you I need to do two splits for the data?. I edited..

Comment: No only one split into train and test, but after the svd transformed data.

Comment: maybe the problem is that I am using pandas... I can not vectorize the full column, right?

Comment: are you getting the error with the tfidfvectorizer in the trace back?

Comment: Yes, I dont get how to reduce the dimention of the dataframe column with SVD and then split the data.

Comment: you can turn the pandas column to an array  `X=df['string_coloumn'].values` and pass this to the vectorizer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70191/discussion-between-ml-guy-and-j-bradley).

Comment: By the way- don't forget to increase the component parameter of the SVD. I set it to 2 for the toy dataset.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know much about `sklearn`, though I vaguely recall some earlier issue triggered by a switch to using sparse matricies.  Internally some of the matrices had to replaced by `m.toarray()` or `m.todense()`.

But to give you an idea of what the error message was about, consider

```
In [907]: A=np.array([[0,1],[3,4]])
In [908]: M=sparse.coo_matrix(A)
In [909]: len(A)
Out[909]: 2
In [910]: len(M)
...
TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]

In [911]: A.shape[0]
Out[911]: 2
In [912]: M.shape[0]
Out[912]: 2
```

`len()` usually is used in Python to count the number of 1st level terms of a list.  When applied to a 2d array, it is the number of rows.  But `A.shape[0]` is a better way of counting the rows. And `M.shape[0]` is the same.  In this case you aren't interested in `.getnnz`, which is the number of nonzero terms of a sparse matrix.  `A` doesn't have this method, though can be derived from `A.nonzero()`.