# Does Keras 1.0 support scipy sparse matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, keras

I can't find a definitive answer on whether keras supports scipy sparse matrices as training / testing vectors. I've read this link, which seems to imply that it doesn't https://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-trip-type-classification/forums/t/18154/training-neural-network-with-scipy-sparse-matrix. This PR seems to imply that it does, though https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/1886. The docs don't state explicitly -- could someone shed some light?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314337/typeerror-sparse-matrix-length-is-ambiguous-use-getnnz-or-shape0-while-usi - similar question using a different machine learning package and sparse matrices

Comment: The PR appears to just convert the sparse matrix to array (`.toarray()`).  As a general rule a sparse matrix requires `sparse` functions and its own methods to work.  Remember it uses the `matrix` conventions for matrix multiplication and element by element multiplication.

Comment: You can train your neural net in batches, so you can limit your `.toarray()` call to each batch and not the whole dataset to use memory efficiently.