# Use sparse Input in Keras with Tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use Sparse numpy matrix for keras with tensorflow as backend. The model compiles but while fit, gives an error. Code is as follows. Any help is appreciated.

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model
inputs = Input(shape=(trainX.shape[1],), sparse=True)
outputs = Dense(trainY.shape[1], activation='softmax')(inputs)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

trainX is

```
<2404941x337071 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 4765705 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

and similarly trainY is a CSR matrix

```
model.fit(trainX, trainY, verbose=1)
```

gives following error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: If the documentation (e.g. for `fit`) doesn't say an argument can be a sparse matrix, then it can't.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803689/does-keras-1-0-support-scipy-sparse-matrices.  Often, if an input is not an array, code will wrap it in `np.asarray(trainX)`.  If the input is sparse, the result is a 1 element object array, which is not what you want.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. But why would they have a sparse option then? and here https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4984 some guys claim to have solved the problem @hpaulj

Comment: And here too: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/260770_e9f31a39cea94ff1b5616fe8b6b4ff28.html#18

Comment: I think that for sparse tensors, a custom batch generator is used that converts just a part of the tensor back into its dense form. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609892/keras-sparse-matrix-issue

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use sparse matrices as inputs to a Keras model if you write a custom training loop.
In the example below, the model takes a sparse matrix as an input and outputs a dense matrix.

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model
import scipy
import numpy as np

trainX = scipy.sparse.random(1024, 1024)
trainY = np.random.rand(1024, 1024)

inputs = Input(shape=(trainX.shape[1],), sparse=True)
outputs = Dense(trainY.shape[1], activation='softmax')(inputs)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

steps = 10
for i in range(steps):
  # For simplicity, we directly use trainX and trainY in this example
  # Usually, this is where batches are prepared
  print(model.train_on_batch(trainX, trainY))
# [3549.2546, 0.0]
# ...
# [3545.6448, 0.0009765625]
```

From your example, it seems that you would like your output to be a sparse matrix too. This is more difficult as your model needs to output a sparse matrix and your loss has to be computable with sparse matrices. Moreover, I believe Keras does not support sparse outputs yet.

Comment: I got this error -> Attempt to convert a value (<1024x1024 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
 with 10485 stored elements in COOrdinate format>) with an unsupported type (<class 'scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix'>) to a Tensor.